# Email toggle for iPhone SBSettings

Tags: iphone, email

I'm just an enthusiast and I've been learning from several tutorials.

I want to write a toggle for SBSettings to allow me to enable/disable a specific email account (I have more than one email accout set up, and I want to be able to enable/disable one of them from SBSettings. The same as: Settings-->Email, contacts, calendar-->Account xx--> Toggle on/off.

I haven't begun yet, so I would be grateful if you could point me in the right direction (including how the settings for email accounts work) on how I should try an implement this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would be surprised if that was possible by any official API.

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://thebigboss.org/guides-iphone-ipod-ipad/sbsettings-toggle-spec) might be a good place to start.